# Grails findBy query with foreign key

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm trying to fetch a user profile picture from the DB by calling the `getProfiePicture()` method on `User` object.

**Method call** from view:

```
<p>${user.getProfilePicture()}</p>
```

**User.groovy** domain class:

```
class Picture {

  User user
  String url
  boolean profile = false
  boolean verified = true
  
  static belongsTo = [user: User]

  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

**Picture.groovy** domain class:

```
class User {
  
  static hasMany = [pictures: Picture]

  String uid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
  String username
  String password

  String getProfilePicture() {
    log.debug("ID: " + id)
    log.debug("UID: " + uid)
    log.debug("Pictures: " + pictures)
    return Picture.findByUserIdAndProfile(id, true)
  }
  
}
```

**Picture** table:
[image]

#### Problem

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to get the profile picture:

```
Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException
Message
No property found for name [userId] for class [class foo.Picture]
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:

- Grails 2.4.4

Comment: `Picture` doesn't have a property `userId` it has a property `user` so you could use `findByUserAndProfile(user, true)`

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Yes, that did it!

Comment: Yep, I knew it would ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getProfilePicture()` method inside your `User` domain class should return the following:

```
Picture.findByUserAndProfile(this, true)
```

The reason you're getting that error is because you are trying to find a `Picture` instance by `userId`, a field which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `getProfilePicture` as following:

```
String getProfilePicture() {
    Picture.where { user == this && profile == true}.first().url
}
```

Alternatively you can use a dynamic Finder (as shown in the comments). By the way: the Picture Class does not need to create the user Attributes twice. `static belongsTo = [user: User]` is enough.

Comment: I removed the `belongsTo` as you suggested, all is good, but I went JoshuaMoore's answer. Thanks!